# Rules to follow while writing a chemical formula for polyatomic ions

Tags: atoms, molecules, notation

In *Science, textbook for class IX, chapter $3$* [[1,p.38](https://ncert.nic.in/textbook/pdf/iesc103.pdf)], it states:

> The rules that you have to follow while writing a chemical formula are as follows:
>
> 1. in compounds formed with polyatomic ions, the number of ions present in the compound is indicated by enclosing the formula of ion in a bracket and writing the number of ions outside the bracket. For example, $\ce{Mg(OH)2}$. [...]

Now my book further states that hydroxide ($\ce{OH–}$) and nitrate ($\ce{NO3-}$) are polyatomic ions. And then it says:

> Formula of sodium nitrate:  $\ce{NaNO3}$

But the formula of calcium hydroxide:  $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$

My question is that even though both nitrate and hydroxide are polyatomic, why are we using ( ) in notation for latter in their symbolic representations?

Comment: Which book is this from?

Comment: https://ncert.nic.in/textbook/pdf/iesc103.pdf - please look at pg 29 and also google search says so - but I could not get the reason why () are used for later and not for former?

Comment: Well, simply put if you wish to write it as so, you would have the compounds to be $\ce{NaNO3}$(sodium nitrate) and Calcium hydroxide as $\ce{CaOH2}$ instead of $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$. The former having 2 hydrogens and one oxygen, wherein reality, it has two oxygens and two hydrogens.

Comment: So CaOH2  instead of Ca(OH)2 are both same? So it is not important to have the brackets - google says Ca(OH)2 or CaH2O2 are same?

Comment: No.. $\ce{CaOH2}$ means that the compound has two hydrogens, one oxygen and one calcium. However we know that Calcium hydroxide should have **two** oxygens, two hydrogens and one calcium.. The entire composition changes. $\ce{OH-}$ is a hydroxide group. and we need two of them to balance charges.

Comment: So NaNO3 means one atom of Na and N but 3 atoms of O so thats why we do not use the bracket in it? Is there a way that we can understand when for polyatomic we need to make use of brackets and not - if we take the one in the question as example then one should be knowing that one atom of N is used instead of 3 for O but not in case for Ca(OH)2 - I mean is () means like group in mathematics?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111540/discussion-between-safdar-and-programmer).

Comment: I'll add a odd clarification to the question. The book chapter linked by the OP does indeed refer to brackets, [ ], but I've never seen anything but parenthesis, ( ), used to defined a polyatomic functional group. // Maybe this is a US vs British English thing??

Comment: @MaxW They are ( ), it is just that the font makes it look different. [ ] is used for co-ordination complexes.

Comment: @MaxW, comment in comment, lol

Answer (score 2):

What they are trying to say is that hydroxide $\ce{OH^−}$ and nitrate $\ce{NO3^−}$ ions, which are polyatomic anions react bond with cations as a group.

When $\ce{NO3^−}$ bonds to $\ce{Na^+}$ only a single nitrate anion bonds to a single sodium cation, to form $\ce{NaNO_3}$ so brackets are not needed. You can still use them, in which case it would be $\ce{NaNO_3}$ but it is redundant and current convention doesn't use it.

However, when $\ce{OH^−}$ bonds to $\ce{Ca^{2+}}$ two hydroxide anions bond to a single calcium cation, to form $\ce{Ca(OH)_2}$ so brackets are needed to avoid confusion and show the structure of the compound.

Old ways of writing it (before my time) before the conventions were standardised, such as $\ce{CaO2H2}$ or $\ce{CaH2O2}$ don't immediately show that it is a hydroxide, so would have been confusing to non-experts.

To reiterate: the brackets are used when there is more than one polyatomic ion in a compound.  So if you write down sodium hydroxide it is $\ce{NaOH}$ but calcium hydroxide is $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$

Comment: [See here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/88/63955) on how to write professional chemical formulas, using the `mhchem` extension.

Comment: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized. According to IUPAC guidelines, they have to be upright.

Answer (score 0):

There is a direct analogy in mathematics.  We write $2\cdot(a+b)$, but we do not write $1\cdot (a+b)$. We write just $a + b$.

So we do not write $\ce{Na(NO3)1}$, but just $\ce{NaNO3}$, as the meaning is obvious even without the explicit parentheses. Sometimes, the parentheses are used with implicit index 1, if it supports the structural clarity of complexes with mixed ligands, like e.g. $\ce{[Fe(H2O)5(OH)]^2+}$ or $\ce{[Fe(CN)5(NO)]^2-}$

OTOH, as there are 2 $\ce{OH}$ groups in calcium hydroxide, we writ0e $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$.